# How can I calculate the accuracy of spelling correction?

Tags: python, nlp, textblob

I'm working in a code for extract wrong words in a text, I'm using python with "textblob" library. In this library there is a function `correction()`, but it just returns the correct phrase based on the wrong phrase, for example:

```
in: b = TextBlob("I havv goood speling!")
in: print(b.correct())
out: I have good spelling!
```

I would like calculate the accuracy of the correction, i.e. obtain the percentage of the correction based on the original text or just obtain the quantity of wrong words in the text.

Someone can help me with that?

Comment: It is quite easy to obtain a number of changed words. Extract all words, get the corrected sentence and get the words from it, and check which words in the new list are missing in the original. Is that enough? BTW, why `spacy` tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`correct` method](https://textblob.readthedocs.io/en/dev/api_reference.html#textblob.blob.Word.correct) does not return confidence, [`Word.spellcheck`](https://textblob.readthedocs.io/en/dev/api_reference.html#textblob.blob.Word.spellcheck) does. However, it does not really help as correct words and those that were fixed with highest confidence have 1.0 confidence value and you can't deduce how many words got corrected.

You may get their number by getting the original word list, fixed word list and then use a list comprehension to get the words missing in the original list:

```
from textblob import TextBlob
text = 'I havv goood speling!'
orig_words = text.split()
fixed_words = TextBlob(text).correct().split()
print(len([(x,y) for x,y in zip(orig_words, fixed_words) if x != y])) # => 3
```

Comment: Your code works perfectly fine unless there is at least one correctly spelled occurrence of a misspelled word in the original string. For instance, if you run your code with `text = 'I havv goood speling and you have good spelling'`, the result is `0` instead of `3`.

Comment: It might be better to compare the original and fixed string word by word, e.g.: `print(len([(x,y) for x,y in zip(orig_words, fixed_words) if x != y]))`

Comment: @jofrev You are right, I got distracted by the original sample sentence.

Answer (score 0):

For string comparison, you normally use Levensthein distance. This is important for "how wrong" a word was, For the accuracy of correction, you need language data to check whether the output of correction() is correct, but I think you just want to have a number telling you what ratio of the text had to be corrected, which is straightforward statistics of counting false positives, true positives, true negatives and false negatives. just google "precision", "recall" and "f-score".